# Nginx docker container stops working

Tags: nginx, ssl, docker, https, containers

First time working on Nginx and cant find why my container suddenly stops working.

I use the nginx image from docker images and before enabling https it was working without issues.

This is the nginx.conf file I added to the image to create https/SSL connection with my nginx container

```
#file used to configure https server with self-signed certificated. this file is used by azure/docker-scripts/docker-e2e-group.yaml
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
#https://localhost
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name localhost;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.key;

    ssl_buffer_size 8k;

    # ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem; can use a pem file here.

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # OCSP stapling
    # ssl_stapling on;
    # ssl_stapling_verify on;
    # resolver 8.8.8.8;

    #return 301 https://localhost$request_uri;
     location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Dockerfile is a two steps, first one omitted here, but I just compile my angular applications.
Second step.

```
### STAGE 2: Run ###
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

The container after few minutes refuses any connection and doesnt serve the site any more.

Any troubleshooting help would be pretty appreciated. Quite lost even what to look at from now on.

Comment: Log files would be helpful. Increase log verbosity if necessary.

Comment: Can you upload log file. You can access log file with dokcer cp or add volume to container to save outside of container.

Comment: I entered in the container using docker exec -it. When I make a cat error.log I am not getting anything back from the container, cat command just hangs out without giving me any logs.